# How to make an sprite bounce within an object?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a ball bounce within a circle so it cant get out of the circumference of the circle. Now the ball bounce in self.frame. How can I make the ball bounce within the circle?

```
let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    sceneBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = sceneBody

    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 9)
    ball.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    ball.position = view.center
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 9)
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(ball)

    circulo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circuloFondo2")
    //Circle that I want the ball bounce within
    circulo.size = CGSize(width:view.frame.size.width - padding , height: view.frame.size.width - padding)
    circulo.color = UIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1)
    circulo.colorBlendFactor = 1
    circulo.alpha = 0.35
    circulo.position = view.center
    self.addChild(circulo)
    circulo.zPosition = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've prepared a simple test project to explain how to do it:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
        case Circle = 1
        case Ball = 2
        //case Enemy1 = 4
        //case Enemy2 = 8
        //case Enemy3 = 16
        //case EnemyBoss = 32
    }

    var circulo: SKSpriteNode!
    var padding: CGFloat = 40.0
    var center: CGPoint!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -6)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        // Prepare circle
        circulo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circuloFondo2.png")
        //Circle that I want the ball bounce within
        circulo.size = CGSize(width:view.frame.size.width - padding , height: view.frame.size.width - padding)
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: (view.frame.size.width - padding*2)/2, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
        circulo.color = UIColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1)
        circulo.colorBlendFactor = 1
        circulo.alpha = 1
        circulo.position = self.center
        circulo.zPosition = 1

        // Set physics
        let circuloBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFromPath: circlePath.CGPath)
        self.physicsBody = circuloBody
        self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody!.mass = 0
        self.physicsBody!.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
        self.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0
        self.physicsBody!.restitution = 1
        self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.Circle.rawValue
        self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.Ball.rawValue
        //self.circulo.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0

        self.addChild(circulo)


        //Prepare ball
        let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 9)
        ball.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        ball.position = self.center
        ball.zPosition = 1

        // Set physics
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 9)
        ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
        ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.8
        ball.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
        ball.physicsBody!.friction = 0.3
        ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        ball.physicsBody!.mass = 0.5
        ball.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
        ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.Ball.rawValue
        ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.Circle.rawValue
        //ball.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0

        self.addChild(ball)

    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        // elements
        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionTypes.Circle.rawValue &&
            contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionTypes.Ball.rawValue) {
            print("contact between circle and ball")
        }
    }
```

The **circuloFondo2** image:

[image]

**A demo** about the project:

[image]

In this answer you can see all the code to do it, but if you want you can download the project [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=50640214828280433151)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alessandro like always, but what if I want that te ball jump higher, i mean that when it bounce the ball always touches the opposite side of where it bounce

Comment: Thank you too. The ball is subjected to the gravity force so you can turn off the gravity only to the ball (affectedByGravity = false) and the ball is stopped forever (like in a spaceship with gravity 0) . To move it you can apply an impulse( let impulse = CGVectorMake(0.0,150.0)
        ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(impulse)  ) and you can see the ball jumping from one side to the other in total absence of gravity. You can do whatever you want by changing the ball physics parameters

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: it tells me that for no reason in the ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(impulse)

Comment: Look here ;) in this project testCirculo2 http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09645285841452514755, probably you set the impulse before to set physics or create the ball.

Comment: Thanks alessandro! we need more people like you